# Can I convert Kiddicarrier jogger to a bike trailer?

Tags: trailer, children

Kiddiecarrier jogger/stroller. Any tips on how to convert/attach to a bike?

[image]

Comment: I've no idea what the answer is but I have a feeling that somebody who needs to ask a question like this probably doesn't have the skills necessary to do the conversion safely.

Comment: Might be a better option is to sell the current Jogger, and purchase a bike trailer with Jogger conversion.

Comment: *Some* models can be converted with a manufacturer's kit.  This could plausibly be one of them.  Check the exact model to find out.  If there's no kit, forget it, or consider it a project in building a kid-safe trailer using this as a source of parts - do you have the skills/time to do that properly?

Comment: Do you want to build something or buy something ?

Comment: Thanks all for your insights. I 'inherited' this and not sure of the model. Was preparing for sale and wanted to buy the conversion kit to sell with, but take on all points to leave unless it has a manufacturer's conversation kit. I really appreciate everyone's time and input. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you’re transporting kids then I’d stick with the manufacturer’s conversion kit if they have one. If they don’t have one, then I’d sell your trolley and buy one that does have a conversion kit. You don’t want to explain to your spouse or parents why their kid/grandkid died in a horrific accident when your DIY trailer hack came apart in a busy intersection.

Otherwise, if you’re carrying cargo the DIY conversion isn’t hard. You just need to first decide if you want to put the hitch on one of the axles or tow from the seatpost or rear rack. There’s advantages and disadvantages to both. I have a [question of here that lays it out](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/49632/11160).

[Fabricating and mounting a drawbar](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/51513/11160) isn’t too hard. The folks at the hardware store can help you bend pipe or conduit and sell you pipe clamps to mount the drawbar.

Then you need to buy a [quick release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/49804/11160) or make your own. They’re not hard to make but hard to make well. They sell kits on amazon.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you flip up the pram onto its back "wall" and have a close look at the chassis.

Here's a kiddicarrier 202 model with the tow-arm extended

[image]
[image]

If you don't have the structure to hold a support arm you will have to buy or make one.

If the support arm is there but folded away then you may already have what you need.

Comment: Thanks Criggie - thjnk it's best to leave as a jogger but do appreciate the time and explanation.